# How to view images in GridView with its original dimensions

Tags: android, xml, layout, gridview, imageview

I want to display a set of images in GridView (They have the same dimensions).
Below the layout for the GirdView and the GirdView Item ..
Teh problem is that the image height is stretched. why ?

GridView layout :

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvRecipes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
</GridView>
```

GridView item is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/include21"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRecibeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"

        android:src="@drawable/img1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRecibeName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Crispy Chicken and Sandwich"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: So actually you can set the width and height of imageview fix to view it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In your scale type you have used `fitXY`:

`fitXY`: This one should only be used if disproportionate scaling does not affect the graphic. In the case of bitmap graphics, this is almost always bad to use. This sets the width of the source image to the width of the view, and the height of the source image to the height of the view, without maintaining the aspect ratio of the source image.

Now your `layout` and `imageview` width is `match_parent`, so the image will be shown in full width of your parent view, but for height it is `wrap_content` so the `imageView` will adjust the `actual height` of your each and every image.